# Image absolute path in Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

Do you know if there are any chance to define the image absolute path before uploading an image into Content Builder?

Comment: Do you mean the URL, or the breadcrumbs of the folder structure inside of SFMC?

Comment: The absolute URL.  When uploading to portfolio, your images have a static URL which you could easily find/replace in your source HTML (from an agency).  Now, when uploading to content builder, all URLs have unique ID's.